# Styling GWT FlexTable only with CSS

Tags: css, gwt, flextable

How do I style a GWT FlexTable using only CSS? The [API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html) mentions nothing about which CSS classes are available.

Aren't there any classes and do I have to set them myself?

I would for instance like to do styling on "th".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FlexTable (which extends [HTMLTable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.html)) doesn't appear to apply any particular styles the cells it contains. There are two possible solutions:

1. Apply a style to the enclosing FlexTable and use descendent selectors (`.myFlexTable th {}`) to style the cells.
2. Use a [CellFormatter](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.CellFormatter.html) to add your own style names to cells in the FlexTable.